# Sharing photo/video on "Photos" (Google Photos) doesn't work from Android app

Tags: android, photos, google-photos

I am trying to upload video to Google Photos app using Share intent ( share intent works fine for Youtube and other services), but it doesn't work well for google PHOTOS. Screen goes to dim state and when I re-start app after pressing home key, google photos login popup is shown again. Is there any way to solve this issue ?  Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you add a sample path to a photo that you are trying to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved

Updated Google+ app